# why is my reducer function getting called multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

my reducer function as per seen the code below, is getting called multiple times causing my incremention to be worng and increment by margins of 2.
i am running this in strictmode so i know it renders one more time to be safe. but it shouldnt affect the state/

```
export const ItemContext = createContext();
export const CartItemContext = createContext();

function reducer(state,action){
  if(action.type === "increment-quantity")
  {
    console.log(state[action.mealIndex][1]);
    state[action.mealIndex][1] +=1 ;
  }
  else if(action.type === "decrement-quantity")
  {

  }
  else if(action.type === "add-meal")
  {
      state = [...state,[action.meal,1]];
  }
  return state;
}


function App() {
  const [orderedMeals,dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,[]);
  const [openModal,setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  const [Quantity,setQuantity] = useState(0);

  const [isFetching,menu,setFetchedData,error]= useFetch(fetchMeals,[]);



  const onAddToCart = (meal) => {
    const mealFound = orderedMeals.find((mealPair) => {return mealPair[0] === meal;})
    const mealIndex = orderedMeals.indexOf(mealFound);
    if(mealFound === undefined)
    {
      dispatch({type:"add-meal",meal:meal})
    }
    else
    {
      dispatch({type:"increment-quantity",mealIndex:mealIndex});
    }
    setQuantity(Quantity+1);
  };
```

i dont know hwo to fix this please help thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

It's due to the direct mutation of the state in your reducer function. You should never mutate the state directly as it can lead to unexpected behavior. Instead, you should return a new state.

## Solution

I’m using the map function to create a new array where the quantity of the required meal is incremented. It ensures that a new state is returned.

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment-quantity":
      return state.map((item, index) =>
        index === action.mealIndex ? [item[0], item[1] + 1] : item
      );
    case "add-meal":
      return [...state, [action.meal, 1]];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much Anshu, this solved my problem perfectly' you taught me something i didnt know about mutating states in the reducer.